# How can i add a third if statement for pandas (python) dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset which works, but i'd like to add a 3rd ifthen statement

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\db\\Desktop\\Pandas\\sans.xls', index_col = 'Department', skiprows=1)
data.rename(columns = {'Employee Number':'Employee_Number', 'Last Name':'Last_Name', 'First Name':'First_Name', 'User Primary Organization':'Organization', 'Manager Full Name':'Manager','Manager Email':'Manager_Email','Department':'Users_Department',}, inplace=True)
new_data = data.drop(['Employee_Number', 'Last_Name', 'First_Name', 'Manager', 'Manager_Email'], axis=1)

training_type = []

for row in data.Organization:
    if row in ['CARB Training', 'Security ISO Team', 'OIS Operations and Support']:
        training_type.append('CARB Security Training')
    elif:
        training_type.append('Phshing')

new_data['training_type'] = training_type
new_data
```

It works as expected, but i want to add a 3rd row, based on 1 more training type

Comment: surely `elif` isn't syntactically correct? I don't see how this can work as expected.

Comment: https://jeffdelaney.me/blog/useful-snippets-in-pandas/

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to add a condition for your `elif`, then add more `elif`s or an `else`:

```
for row in data.Organization:
    if row in ['CARB Training', 'Security ISO Team', 'OIS Operations and Support']:
        training_type.append('CARB Security Training')
    elif row in ['some_other_thing', 'some_other_other_thing']:
        training_type.append('Phshing')
    else:
        training_type.append('third_thing')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing this with one of the `numpy` methods instead, much faster.

**Option 1**
*`np.where`*

- `np.where` with 2 conditions:

  ```
  c1 = ['CARB Training', 'Security ISO Team', 'OIS Operations and Support']

  new_data['training_type'] = np.where(data.Organization.isin(c1), 
                                     'CARB Security Training', 'Phishing')
  ```
- `np.where` with 3 conditions:

  ```
  c1 = ['CARB Training', 'Security ISO Team', 'OIS Operations and Support']
  c2 = [....]

  new_data['training_type'] = \
         np.where(data.Organization.isin(c1), 'CARB Security Training', 
         np.where(data.Organization.isin(c2), 'SomethingElse', 'Phishing'))
  ```

---

**Option 2**
*`np.select`*

```
m1 = data.Organization.isin(c1)
m2 = data.Organization.isin(c2)
m3 = m1 | m2

new_data['training_type'] = np.select([m1, m2, ~(m1 | m2)], 
              ['CARB Security Training', 'SomethingElse', 'Phishing'])
```